# Symfony 2 Multiple Selects with counts on the same table?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

Ok I have a flag field on one table, open or closed which is boolean. I am trying to build one query that would take that field and count them based on that flag. Then I will need to group them by account ID

Here is what I am working with now,

```
   $GetTest1 = $GetRepo->createQueryBuilder('s') <- I had 'w' in here but all that did was add an index and not a second alias?
                                ->select(' (count(s.open_close)) AS ClosedCount, (count(w.open_close)) AS OpenCount ')
                                ->where('s.open_close = ?1')
                                //->andWhere('w.open_close = ?2')
                                ->groupBy('s.AccountID')
                                ->setParameter('1', true)
                                //->setParameter('2', false)
                                ->getQuery();
```

Is what I want do-able? I know (or at lest think) that I can build a query with multiple table alias? - Please correct me if I am wrong.

All help most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This DQL query will group the rows in table by accountId and for each of them it will give you count for yes (and you can get count for no by substracting that from total).
BTW I found writing straight DQL queries much more straightforward than writing QueryBuilder queries (which i use only when i need to dynamically construct the query)

```
$results = $this->get("doctrine")->getManager()
    ->createQuery("
    SELECT t.accountId, SUM(t.openClose) as count_yes, COUNT(t.accountId) as total
    FROM AppBundle:Table t 
    GROUP BY t.accountId
    ")
    ->getResult();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    //echo print_r($result);
    //you can get count_no as $result["total"] - $result["count_yes"];
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for that! - I was told somewhere, at sometime that it was recommended to use the QueryBuilder over use DQL. I give this ago! I am getting a few issues with the QueryBuilder output, for some reason some of my pages are making over 50 queries! Which I am sure is not right, problem for a later date... :)

Comment: Thanks Mate, I got it to work with that Query, I thinking of going though the site and moving over to DQL throughout my current project. Many thanks